# How do we question a non-author deletion?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11173133/208880) deleted, but no reason given as to why and nothing obvious in the answer as to why.

Anybody have any ideas why?  Was this an abuse of power?

Comment: OP left a comment stating that the answer didn't answer his question.

Comment: Part of the value of StackOverflow is that persons besides the original asker can learn.  At least one such thought the deleted answer was decent as it had an upvote.  I can see no valid reason for the deletion of this answer.

Comment: @Robert Harvey, I had the same question. But i don't mind if Moderator deleted my answer which I plagiarized from other site and even had one upvote. My question is if Moderators know its not a right answer than why don't they help the person who asked the question and than delete the wrong answer. They just leave a comment and done. No Questions asked, Although i know they have a tough job to do, still they can answer us why was that wrong, and help us not to commit such mistake again. It's like sharing their knowledge nothing else.

Comment: @KrunalPatil Moderators don't normally have the time for that sort of thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I'm seeing here is an answer that actually does not answer the OP's issue. I read the answer, read the question without having read the comments, and right there and then I knew `multiprocessing` would not work. Why? Because it requires a parent-child relationship between the processes. While it is true the OP does not specify that the daemons are not in a parent-child relationship, I don't think *assuming* that they are (which is a prerequisite to using `multiprocessing`) is wise.

In the past, when I've posted answers that missed an important aspect of what the OP wants, I've deleted them myself, even if I got one or multiple upvotes on my answer. If someone with the power to delete my answer had done so before I did, would it have made a difference? No, because my answer should have been deleted *anyway*.

It seems to me it is *possible* that the author of the answer decided that this answer should remain deleted.

Besides the fact that the answer does not provide what the OP wanted, it also appears to me to be a link-only answer. I've read Shog's [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) about such answers. The fact is that no matter how objective we try to be, there remains place for subjectivity when it comes to whether an answer is link-only. Here I'd say that pointing out the existence of `multiprocessing` does not answer the question substantially enough to avoid the fault of being link-only. The person using this answer still has to figure out what part of `multiprocessing` would pertain to the task at hand. So if this answer was deleted on the basis that it was a link-only answer, I would not find this problematic at all.

I'm not seeing an abuse of power here.

Comment: Thanks.  With that extra bit of knowledge (parent-child relationship required) I can see that the answer was not useful.  I think, however, that adding that bit in a comment would have added more value than removing the answer.

Comment: @EthanFurman - I think Louis has it right with this explanation. Another user flagged this as a link-only answer that needed to be deleted, and a moderator agreed with that assessment. I might have let it stay, but the community is generally opposed to answers like this. It wasn't about the technical correctness of the answer, just whether a link like that is acceptable as an answer at all.

Comment: @BradLarson: Ah, I can't see flags so didn't have that bit of info either.  Thanks.